# What does "true mean is not equal to 0" mean in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing test for set a data and a statement appears

> true mean is not equal to 0

What does it mean?

```
t.test(Spread.sheet.VNV.Height$Height..CM.2,conf.level = .90)

    One Sample t-test

data:  Spread.sheet.VNV.Height$Height..CM.2
t = 11.648, df = 31, p-value = 7.432e-13
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
90 percent confidence interval:
 18.87785 25.30965
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 22.09375
```

Comment: The null hyopthesis is that the mean is equal to 0. The alternative is that its not. The p-value is extremely close to 0, which means the probability of getting this result if the null was true is near 0%. So we can confidently reject the null.

Comment: @Phil That looks like an answer!

Comment: It means that You can reject the null.

Comment: $H_0:~\mu = 0,~H_A:~\mu \neq 0$ Stating the null-hypothesis and its alternative is a crucial part of a hypothesis test. The alternative hypothesis is stated here to distiguish the two-sided test from one-sided tests.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the entire line, since it specifies that it is telling you the alternative hypothesis for the test:

> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0

In a [one sample T-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#One-sample_t-test) you have a specified value for the true mean under the null hypothesis.  In the present case your null hypothesis is that the true mean is zero and the alternative hypothesis is that it is not zero.  (Note that the null value is set using the `mu` value in the [`t.test` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test); by default this is set to zero.)